# Ruby on Rails Foreign Keys Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, foreign-keys

I am trying to get a handle on how to use foreign keys in Rails,

```
$ rails g scaffold categories cat:string value:integer
$ rails db:migrate
```

Then create a new table with a foreign key connecting to the first table categories,

```
$ rails g scaffold subcategories subcats:string subcatsvalue:integer categories:references 
$ rails db:migrate
```

Then I append /categories to the url and the form is there as expected and I can do all CRUD operations.

Then I append /subcategories to the url and try to add some data to the form such as,

Subcats: blah
Subcatsvalue: 123
Categories: cat1

should this be the id of the category or the name of the category?

/RubyLearningApp/db/migrate/20200413195730_create_categories.rb

```
class CreateCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :categories do |t|
      t.string :cat
      t.integer :value

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

/RubyLearningApp/db/migrate/20200413200303_create_subcategories.rb

```
class CreateSubcategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :subcategories do |t|
      t.string :subcats
      t.integer :subcatsvalue
      t.references :categories, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Is this correct way to set up a foreign key between tables?

When I fill in the Categories with 'cat1' I get the following error,

[image]

Schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20200413200303) do

  create_table "categories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "cat"
    t.integer  "value"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "subcategories", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "subcats"
    t.integer  "subcatsvalue"
    t.integer  "categories_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.index ["categories_id"], name: "index_subcategories_on_categories_id"
  end

end
```

The model files:

category.rb

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
end
```

subcategory.rb

```
class Subcategory < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :categories
end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Thanks,

Comment: can you post the head of your model files?

Comment: I posted those and notice that there is something very strange there, they are called category.rb and subcategory.rb , shouldn't them be categories.rb and subcategories.rb ? I was trying to build this previously and must not have deleted everything perhaps. How should i proceed best from here?

Comment: rails models use singulars. change belongs_to :categories into belongs_to :category and see how that goes. Also under Category, add: has_many :subcategories. Altho tbh I'd remove all that and start from scratch.

Comment: Does this error happen in development and production? Your screenshot appears to be in production.

Comment: @hashrocket this is in development I am just testing to figure out how to get foreign keys to work for the simplest case I can create. Thanks for your help

Comment: @NickM yes I agree I should start again and thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your scaffolds that may be causing the problems. The correct way to generate a scaffold is to use a singular scaffold name:

```
rails g scaffold Category
```

and

```
rails g scaffold SubCategory
```

This will use Rails built in Inflector to pluralize the names where necessary.

When using references, you should also use the singular:

```
category:references
```

This is the `Rails Way` and it will sort out most of the problems you are having. The other issue is if you want to add the category to the url, you should nest your routes:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :sub_categories
end
```

This will allow you to use routes like

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/1/subcategories
```

and

```
http://localhost:3000/categories/1/subcategories/1
```

The first number (the one closest to the left) is the category id and can be access by using `params[:category_id]` in the `sub_categories_controller.rb` file. The second number (the one closest to the right) is the sub_category id and can be accessed by `params[:id]` in the `sub_categories_controller.rb` file.

Answer (score -1):

Well, after spending two days stuck figuring out how to solve the foreign key issue in Rails 6+ - even though i read a lot of comments from S.O which did not do much help. I finally found the solution.

Using `add_reference` in your migration, you can easily solve this.

Let's pick it up from where you have model files untouched and Rails generated.

For your `Category` Model, you should have:

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :subcategories, foreign_key: :categories_id
end
```

And for your `Subcategory` Model, you should have:

```
class SucCategory < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category. foreign_key: :categories_id
end
```

This creates an Association atrribute that tells rails that a `Category` has many `Subcategories` that can be identified in the `categories` table by a foreign key found in the `subcategories` table known as *categories_id*

Then in your console, now run the command `rails generate migration AddSubcategoriesToCategories` to create a migration file. Within the generated migration file, be sure to have the `change` method;

```
class AddSubcategoriesToCategories < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
    def change
        add_references :categories, :categories, references: :subcategories, type: :integer, index: false
    end
end
```

This would create a *categories_id* column in your `categories` table and tells ActiveRecord to reference the values(s) from the `subcategories` table, automatically making it a foreign key.

Funny enough, the reason why the option `:categories` appears a second time is because ActiveRecord by default, looks for the column named *id* within the table from which the foreign key is taken - as it is the default index on creating tables. But as a different column with a different name is defined as the index, you will have to specify the name of the column *(eg. keyname)* in the `add_reference` function to make ActiveRecord append the phrase *_id* to what you just defined as the column name and find that column - now named 'keyname_id', else you'll receive errors that specify that *the column 'id' referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist* or if you specify the full column name as *'keyname_id'* in your `add_reference` function, you'll receive errors that specify that *the column 'keyname_id' referenced in foreign key constraint does not exit*

So in this case the second `:categories` in the function is the first part of the name of the column to which ActiveRecord appends the remaining part **'_id'** to become `:categories_id`.

*Drawback: All your foreign keys would then have to be snakecased as **'whateverkeyname_id'** in your tables*

Comment: I think this answer is wrong and the answer above is right.  While this does work it breaks the rails convention and you are then having to introduce hacks to make it work again.  If you use the singular as in the answer above then your foreign key will be automatically set to "category_id" rather than "categories_id" and then you don't need to set the index to false or define a foreign key in your model...